# Tried to remove lamp-server, now my X won't work

Tags: boot, uninstall, lamp

I did this command to install: sudo apt-get install lamp-server^

I did this one to uninstall: sudo apt-get remove lamp-server^

It uninstalled a LOT of things, and now my system won't go to X. I tried sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop, and it made possible to start X in other screen, but without gnome or unity.

How do I recover my desktop?

Comment: I solved it, but I don't have enough characters here to explain how, and can't answer my own question because I have just created this account and have less than 10 reputation. I'll leave the solution in 8 hours or after I get 1 more upvote.

Comment: Can you post your answer for the benefit of future visitors?

Comment: @Mahesh I already did, mate. Look down below

Comment: Oops. Blame the new review system. :/ It showed me only the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I didn't find anything while searching for a solution, but I found more information about the problem:

These are the packages that are uninstalled when you try to remove lamp-server the way I did:

```
apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common bluez-cups cups cups-driver-gutenprint cups-pdf foo2zjs gdm gdm-guest-session gecko-mediaplayer gnome-applets gnome-control-center gnome-media gnome-mplayer gnome-panel gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon goldendict gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio hpijs hplip hplip-cups indicator-applet indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-applet-complete indicator-sound libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libasound2-plugins libcanberra-pulse libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhpmud0 libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient16 libnet-daemon-perl libphonon4 libplrpc-perl libpulse-browse0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libqtwebkit4 libsane-hpaio libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio libsnmp15 libwrap0 mplayer mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf pulseaudio-utils pxljr python-speechd speech-dispatcher splix ssl-cert tcpd vlc-plugin-pulse
```

So this is what solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common bluez-cups cups cups-driver-gutenprint cups-pdf foo2zjs gdm gdm-guest-session gecko-mediaplayer gnome-applets gnome-control-center gnome-media gnome-mplayer gnome-panel gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon goldendict gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio hpijs hplip hplip-cups indicator-applet indicator-applet-appmenu indicator-applet-complete indicator-sound libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libasound2-plugins libcanberra-pulse libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhpmud0 libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient16 libnet-daemon-perl libphonon4 libplrpc-perl libpulse-browse0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libqtwebkit4 libsane-hpaio libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio libsnmp15 libwrap0 mplayer mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 phonon phonon-backend-gstreamer php5-cli php5-common php5-mysql pulseaudio pulseaudio-esound-compat pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-gconf pulseaudio-module-x11 pulseaudio-module-zeroconf pulseaudio-utils pxljr python-speechd speech-dispatcher splix ssl-cert tcpd vlc-plugin-pulse
```